# How to keep all intent String values even app is closed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I am doing one small app in that app i am saving some values in intent using putExtra and sending that values to  broadcast reciever.in broadcast if sms is sent i am getting the values using getstring.its working fine only when app is open.so i need to keep all the intent values even app is closed.

Comment: refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Use shared preferences

Comment: thank you.is it any other way to do this with out using shared preferences.

Comment: @Karthik you can use sqlite but IMO shared preferences is more suitable

Comment: yes you ca use Sqlite db if the data is huge or even files

Comment: since your data is less for storage as pooya said its good to go with SharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

// use getActivity if used from Fragment otherwise use this

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("VAL", "AV");
editor.commit();
//get the data like
 String value=mSharedPreferences.getString("VAL", "null")
```

Comment: getActivity() is deprecated, he should use getContext() instead

Comment: getActivity() of fragment is deprecated now ?

Comment: do you have any reference please

Comment: ops, my bad. it is not!. onAttach(Activity context) it is

Comment: thats why i asked you for reference , even i was not able to understand.